# Python random while multiple conditions

Tags: python, random, multiple-conditions

Cheers, my problem is that I don't know how to do a while with multiple conditions. I really don't get it why this won't work:

```
import random

a = 0
b = 0
c = 0

while a < 190 and b < 140 and c < 110: # <-- This condition here
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0

    for i in range(1, 465):
        v = random.randint(1, 3)

        if v == 1:
            a = a + 1
        elif v == 2:
            b = b + 1
        else:
            c = c + 1

    result = ""
    result += "a: " + str(a) + "\n"
    result += "b: " + str(b) + "\n"
    result += "c: " + str(c) + "\n"

    print (result)
```

I want to loop this until a is above 190 AND b above 140 AND c above 110 but it stops everytime after the first run.

Can someone help me there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change the logically slightly and use an infinite loop that you then `break` out of when your conditions are met:

```
while True:
    # do stuff
    if a >= 190 and b >= 140 and c >=110:
        break
```

Your original logic terminated if *any* of the conditions were met. For example, this loop exits because `a` is no longer `True` after the first iteration:

```
a = True 
b = True
while a and b:
    a = False
```

This loop is infinite because `b` is always `True`:

```
a = True
b = True
while a or b:
    a = False
```

You could use `or` instead of `and` for your initial `while` loop, but I find the `break` logic far more intuitive.

Comment: I want that I start the algorithm everytime with 0, so it's not possible to get over 465 total. Thats why I did this. Btw, this answer did it. Can you tell me why the while-condition didn't work?

Comment: @PatrickMlr Your initial `while` loop will exit if *any* of these conditions are met. For example, if `a = 191` then the loop will terminate

Comment: So and is in python or? Thats strange.

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting `a`, `b` and `c` in the body of the loop.
Try this:

```
>>> count = 0
>>> while a < 190 and b < 140 and c < 110 and count < 10: # <-- This condition here
...   count += 1
...   a = 0
...   b = 0
...   c = 0
...   print(count, a, b, c)
... 
(1, 0, 0, 0)
(2, 0, 0, 0)
(3, 0, 0, 0)
(4, 0, 0, 0)
(5, 0, 0, 0)
(6, 0, 0, 0)
(7, 0, 0, 0)
(8, 0, 0, 0)
(9, 0, 0, 0)
(10, 0, 0, 0)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are only showing "a,b,c" when the while loop iterates and you incrementing in each loop 465 times. This means if your while loop works 4 times its gonna increment a, b, c randomly 465*4 times. and your values too way small for this kinda increment. As a solution you can decrease 465 number if you make it 250 you'll see it'll work until c reaches over 110 and finishes iterating.

```
for i in range(1, 250):
    v = random.randint(1, 3)
```

With 250 c reaches 114 and finishes iterating. This because that 250 / 3 ~= 83 . And when the numbers dispenses as randomly c is the most commonly reacher that it's limit. I think that you want something like this;

```
import random

a = 0
b = 0
c = 0

while a < 190 and b < 140 and c < 110: # <-- This condition here
    v = random.randint(1, 3)
    if v == 1:
        a = a + 1
    elif v == 2:
        b = b + 1
    else:
        c = c + 1

    result = ""
    result += "a: " + str(a) + "\n"
    result += "b: " + str(b) + "\n"
    result += "c: " + str(c) + "\n"

    print (result)
```

It will gonna show you each increment one by one and it will gonna stop when some of the requirements meets in while loop.